# Typescript optional chaining esm 2020 not working with node v16 -r esm

Tags: node.js, typescript, optional-chaining

I'm developing a webapp in typescript where i run the program with

```
node -r esm
```

and using import statements, but I have an issue with optional chaining when choosing

```
"target": "ES2020"
```

in the tsconfig.json. It works fine with "ES2019", but I would like to use BigInt's which is not supported in ES2019. I'm using node v16.13.1, so I don't understand why it's not working. From my understanding, this should not happen as optional chaining has been supported since node v14... This is the error I get

```
return jwt.sign({ id: user?.id, email: user?.email }, secret, {
                               ^
SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

Full tsconfig.

```
{
  "include": ["./src"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Basic Options */
    // "incremental": true,                   /* Enable incremental compilation */
    "target": "ES2020" /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017', 'ES2018', 'ES2019', 'ES2020', or 'ESNEXT'. */,
    "module": "ESNEXT" /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', 'es2020', or 'ESNext'. */,
    // "lib": [],                             /* Specify library files to be included in the compilation. */
    // "allowJs": true /* Allow javascript files to be compiled. */,
    // "checkJs": true,                       /* Report errors in .js files. */
    // "jsx": "react" /* Specify JSX code generation: 'preserve', 'react-native', or 'react'. */,
    // "declaration": true,                   /* Generates corresponding '.d.ts' file. */
    // "declarationMap": true,                /* Generates a sourcemap for each corresponding '.d.ts' file. */
    // "sourceMap": true,                     /* Generates corresponding '.map' file. */
    // "outFile": "./",                       /* Concatenate and emit output to single file. */
    "outDir": "./dist" /* Redirect output structure to the directory. */,
    // "rootDir": "./",                       /* Specify the root directory of input files. Use to control the output directory structure with --outDir. */
    // "composite": true,                     /* Enable project compilation */
    // "tsBuildInfoFile": "./",               /* Specify file to store incremental compilation information */
    // "removeComments": true,                /* Do not emit comments to output. */
    // "noEmit": true,                        /* Do not emit outputs. */
    // "importHelpers": true,                 /* Import emit helpers from 'tslib'. */
    // "downlevelIteration": true,            /* Provide full support for iterables in 'for-of', spread, and destructuring when targeting 'ES5' or 'ES3'. */
    // "isolatedModules": true,               /* Transpile each file as a separate module (similar to 'ts.transpileModule'). */
    /* Strict Type-Checking Options */
    "strict": false /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */,
    // "noImplicitAny": true,                 /* Raise error on expressions and declarations with an implied 'any' type. */
    "strictNullChecks": true /* Enable strict null checks. */,
    // "strictFunctionTypes": true,           /* Enable strict checking of function types. */
    // "strictBindCallApply": true,           /* Enable strict 'bind', 'call', and 'apply' methods on functions. */
    // "strictPropertyInitialization": true,  /* Enable strict checking of property initialization in classes. */
    // "noImplicitThis": true,                /* Raise error on 'this' expressions with an implied 'any' type. */
    // "alwaysStrict": true,                  /* Parse in strict mode and emit "use strict" for each source file. */
    /* Additional Checks */
    // "noUnusedLocals": true,                /* Report errors on unused locals. */
    // "noUnusedParameters": true,            /* Report errors on unused parameters. */
    // "noImplicitReturns": true,             /* Report error when not all code paths in function return a value. */
    // "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,    /* Report errors for fallthrough cases in switch statement. */
    /* Module Resolution Options */
    "moduleResolution": "node" /* Specify module resolution strategy: 'node' (Node.js) or 'classic' (TypeScript pre-1.6). */,
    // "baseUrl": "./",                       /* Base directory to resolve non-absolute module names. */
    // "paths": {},                           /* A series of entries which re-map imports to lookup locations relative to the 'baseUrl'. */
    // "rootDirs": [],                        /* List of root folders whose combined content represents the structure of the project at runtime. */
    // "typeRoots": [],                       /* List of folders to include type definitions from. */
    "types": [
      "jest",
      "node"
    ] /* Type declaration files to be included in compilation. */,
    // "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,  /* Allow default imports from modules with no default export. This does not affect code emit, just typechecking. */
    "esModuleInterop": true /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */,
    // "preserveSymlinks": true,              /* Do not resolve the real path of symlinks. */
    // "allowUmdGlobalAccess": true,          /* Allow accessing UMD globals from modules. */
    /* Source Map Options */
    // "sourceRoot": "",                      /* Specify the location where debugger should locate TypeScript files instead of source locations. */
    // "mapRoot": "",                         /* Specify the location where debugger should locate map files instead of generated locations. */
    // "inlineSourceMap": true,               /* Emit a single file with source maps instead of having a separate file. */
    // "inlineSources": true,                 /* Emit the source alongside the sourcemaps within a single file; requires '--inlineSourceMap' or '--sourceMap' to be set. */
    /* Experimental Options */
    // "experimentalDecorators": true,        /* Enables experimental support for ES7 decorators. */
    // "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,         /* Enables experimental support for emitting type metadata for decorators. */
    /* Advanced Options */
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true /* Disallow inconsistently-cased references to the same file. */,
    "resolveJsonModule": true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hit this issue myself, though not with Typescript. The original `esm` package came before optional chaining became standard, and the original developer stopped supporting the package before support for that kind of syntax was introduced.

From [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/standard-things/esm/issues/866), I found a forked version called [`esm-wallaby`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/esm-wallaby) that *does* support optional chaining and a host of other modern, commonly-used syntaxes.